# How to filter array depending on url parameter

Tags: angularjs

How can one filter an array for one property depending on an url parameter defined as true or not? I have tried the following, but: "Error: $location is not defined". I have made it available to the controller of the template though.

javascript:

```
app.filter('myFilter', function() {

    return function( items ) {
        return items.filter(function(element){
            var ext = ($location.search().ext == "true"); // Check if url contains ?ext=true
            if (ext == true){
                if ( externallyAvailable == 'true') {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            else{
                return true;
            }
        });
    }
});

app.controller('tilesController', ['$scope', '$http', '$sce', '$location', '$filter', function($scope, $http, $sce, $location, $filter) {
    /* some controller logic */
}
```

Template:

```
<li ng-repeat="tile in list.tiles  | myFilter" class="tile-wrapper">
    <!-- content -->
</li>
```

I also find that my solution, if it would work, takes more lines than I'd expect, so other suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to inject the $location Provider in your filter as well. As you haven't done that, That is why it is showing you the undefined error. Try something like this

```
app.filter('myFilter', function($location) {

    return function( items ) {
        return items.filter(function(element, $location){
            var ext = ($location.search().ext == "true"); // Check if url contains ?ext=true
            if (ext == true){
                if ( externallyAvailable == 'true') {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            else{
                return true;
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: And apparently there is no need to inject $location into the controller. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to use the `$location` *service* to check a string (regardless of whether it's a string of a UL)

Here's an untested start for you to work with:

```
app.filter('containsExtParam', function() {

    return function( items ) {
        return items.filter(function(element){
            return element.indexOf('?ext=true') !== -1;
        });
    }
});
```